# MSGraph token error: "Application (...) was not found in the directory"

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm trying to implement the Microsoft Graph for OneDrive access in PHP. I'm going by [this documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user).

I've registered my app at `https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/` and got an App ID and a secret back.

Now, for the token flow, I'm emitting the following link:

```php
$LogonLink = 
"https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?".
 http_build_query(array(
    'client_id' => $MSGraphAppID,
    'response_type' => 'code',
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://www.example.com/ongraph.php',
    'response_mode' => 'query',
    'scope' => 'offline_access Files.ReadWrite'));
```

The logon and permissions UI works as expected, my app's name and icon comes up. So the App ID is recognized. Now, `ongraph.php` gets control with a code, and I emit the following POST:

```php
$cu = curl_init('https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token');
$Form = array(
    'client_id' => $MSGraphAppID,
    'scope' => 'offline_access Files.ReadWrite',
    'code' => $_GET['Code'],
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://www.example.com/ongraph.php',
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'client_secret' => $MSGraphSecret
);
curl_setopt_array($cu, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($Form)));

$r = curl_exec($cu);
```

I'm getting back error `400` and the following response:

```json
{
    "error": "unauthorized_client",
    "error_description": "AADSTS70001: Application with identifier '0000000048205436' was not found in the directory 9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad\r\nTrace ID: b0f7cba6-42b3-4f37-8438-5e8566ba1300\r\nCorrelation ID: ca51b601-86cb-4801-a330-354ffd3c715f\r\nTimestamp: 2017-11-08 17:12:33Z",
    "error_codes": [70001],
    "timestamp": "2017-11-08 17:12:33Z",
    "trace_id": "b0f7cba6-42b3-4f37-8438-5e8566ba1300",
    "correlation_id": "ca51b601-86cb-4801-a330-354ffd3c715f"
}
```

What am I missing here, please? I've tried creating a brand new app registration, same result.

EDIT: that's what the app registration site looks like:

[image: Registration UI screenshot]

Comment: Are you passing `0000000048205436` as your application id?

Comment: Yes, in both places. It's in my config, so a typo is unlikely. The logon UI recognizes it as valid.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your config? Application ID should always be in GUID format.

Comment: As @ShawnTabrizi mentioned, the ID you're sending isn't a valid App ID. The App ID/Client ID should be a GUID (i.e. `af5380a6-432c-4a16-a9d9-61bcb68c3c13`)

Comment: Pasted. I think GUIDs come from the apps registered at Azure AD proper (portal.azure.com) as opposed to Azure AD v2 (which I'm using). Y'all are welcome to navigate to apps.dev.microsoft.com, register a dummy app, see if you get a GUID...

Comment: It looks like you might be creating a legacy application in the Application Registration Portal. Make sure you are clicking "Add an app" in the `Converged applications` section. As you can see in [this screenshot](https://imgur.com/jzWQsMR), the resulting application ids are all GUIDs. My guess is that you are looking at a legacy Live SDK application which is not supported via the AAD V2 endpoint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you've registered your app as a [Live SDK application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn631819.aspx):

[image: Live SDK Application Registration]

For the v2 Endpoint (and Microsoft Graph), you need to register this as a [Converged application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview):

[image: Converged Application]

The https://apps.dev.microsoft.com site handles both application types.